# magento2 - windows php-cgi process not killed

Tags: magento2, php, windows

Being new to magento2, I've installed it upon my windows machine ( along with limited resources, please don't ask me to have a docker setup then .. ).

There's a weird thing happening for each static content request "pub/static/version15../library.js" .. each of those processes are never killed, having then 300+ php-cgi zombie processes stacked within my machine.

1) Is there a simple way of getting rid of this odd behaviour ?

2) I also tried to limit to 1 maximal running php process at the time .. front display was really quick then, but the admin login wasn't working anymore, does anyone have some advices in order to run it smoothly under windows ?

3) Is there a way to "deploy" static content under an unique path so files would be served instantanely through apache ? ( not using version15... )